# Will prefixing the script path with `/usr/bin/env -i` make usage of system() and popen() secure?

Tags: c, security, posix, popen

I am doing a code review right now and I was blown away by the amount of code that the guy wrote just to execute one script (with hard-coded path and no input arguments) and read the output out of it. (BTW he had a lot of bugs in it.)

I encountered a similar issue before and it was suggested to me that doing pipe/fork/exec manually is "more secure". I am aware of two potential problems:

1. As `system()` and `popen()` execute shell commands, it is possible to slip potentially harmful environment variable values to the program executed this way
2. Another is that when the command is constructed from user input. I can imagine subshells doing all kinds of harmful things and so on.

I was wondering if suggesting to use `popen()` instead would be OK in this case. It would greatly simplify the code. The second point is not an issue as there is no user input. By using `env -i` to clean the environment before executing the script should make the first issue go away:

```
FILE *fp = popen("/usr/bin/env -i /path/to/some/fancy/script.sh", "r");
/* ... */
```

Are there any other potential issues I am missing, or is doing the script execution "manually" still worth the effort?

Comment: Big topic.  What you’re proposing will help up to a point, but you need to provide some environment variables (such as PATH), and you’re suddenly on a slippery slope.

Comment: `system()` and `popen()` should be burned as offerings to the god of past programming sins. Trying to make them safe is difficult. And no matter how much you try, *You will fail*. It is much easier to create your own safe version of `popen()` from scratch on top of pipe/fork/exec.

Comment: Oh, and when you go down the fork/exec route, never litter your code with fork/exec. Always wrap them in generic utility functions.

Comment: `env -i /path/to/script.sh` would be safer than `/path/to/script.sh`. But the code that the guy wrote might be safer. Also, the question of "how safer?" depends on what the script does and what environment it needs. For example, if the script receives no input from command line but does receive user input from some file on the machine, or if the script can't be trusted, you still have concerns.

Answer (score 0):

This is technically not your answer to the question on how to call `popen()` safely, but the answer to the question you should have asked: "How to make a better `popen()`"

The function `child_spawn(argv, env, flags)` will set up pipes for communicating with a child process, and spawn the child. It will return a 
`struct child` that holds the child pid and file descriptors for communication.

`argv` is a `NULL` terminated string array of command and arguments, while `env` is a `NULL` terminated string array of environment variables. If `env` is NULL, the child will inherit the environment from the parent.

So `argv` should have the form

```
const char* argv[] = {"/bin/ls", "-l", NULL};
```

And `env` should have the form

```
const char **env = NULL;

or

const char *env[] = 
   {
      "PATH=/bin:/usr/bin",
      "HOME=/tmp",
      "SHELL=/bin/sh",
      NULL
   };
```

When you are finished with the child process, `child_wait()` will close the file descriptors associated with the child and wait for it to exit.

To use `child_spawn()` as a substitute of `popen()` you call it like this:

```
struct child c = child_spawn(argv, NULL, CHILD_PIPE_STDOUT);
```

You may now read from `c->fd_out` to get the content of the childs stdout.

The constants `CHILD_PIPE_STDIN`, `CHILD_PIPE_STDOUT` and `CHILD_PIPE_STDERR` may be "or"-ed together to have a valid file descriptors in `c->fd_in`, `c->fd_out`, `c->fd_err`

Be aware that if you spawn a child with `CHILD_PIPE_STDIN|CHILD_PIPE_STDOUT`, there is a risk of deadlock when reading and writing, unless you do non-blocking io.

The function `my_system()` is an example on how to implement a safer `system()` using `child_spawn()`

```
/*
  We have to #define _GNU_SOURCE to get access to `char **environ`
*/
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <unistd.h>


#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/sendfile.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <error.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>


struct child
{
  pid_t pid;
  int fd_in;
  int fd_out;
  int fd_err;
};

static void
close_if_valid(int fd)
{
  if (fd != -1) close(fd);
}

/* 
   Closes all file-descriptors for child communication
   and waits for child to exit

   returns status value from waitpid().
   see `man waitpid` on how to interpret that value
 */
int child_wait(struct child *c)
{
  close_if_valid(c->fd_in);
  close_if_valid(c->fd_out);
  close_if_valid(c->fd_err);

  int status;

  pid_t p = waitpid(c->pid, &status, 0);
  if (p == 0)
    error(1, errno, "waitpid() failed");

  return status; 
}


int
dup_if_valid(int fd1, int fd2)
{
  if (fd1 != -1 && fd1 != fd2)
    return dup2(fd1, fd2);
  return fd2;
}


pid_t
child_spawn_fd(const char *const argv[], const char *const env[],
           int in, int out, int err)
{
  fflush(stdout);
  pid_t p = fork();

  if (p)
    return p;

  /***********************
    We are now in child
  ***********************/

  /* 
     Set file descriptors to expected values,
     -1 means inherit from parent
  */
  if (dup_if_valid(in, 0) == -1)
    goto CHILD_ERR;

  if (dup_if_valid(out, 1) == -1)
    goto CHILD_ERR;

  if (dup_if_valid(err, 2) == -1)
    goto CHILD_ERR;

  /*
    close all unneeded file descriptors
    This will free resources and keep files and sockets belonging to
    the parent from beeing open longer than needed

    On *BSD we may call `closefrom(3);`, but this may not exits
    on Linux. So we loop over all possible file descriptor numbers.
    A better solution, is to look in `/proc/self/fs`
  */
  int max_fd = sysconf(_SC_OPEN_MAX);

  for (int fd = 3; fd <= max_fd; fd++)
    close(fd);

  if (env)
    environ = (char **)env;

  /* Change to execvp if command should be looked up in $PATH */
  execv(argv[0], (char * const *)argv);

 CHILD_ERR:
  _exit(1);
}


#define CHILD_PIPE_STDIN (1 << 0)
#define CHILD_PIPE_STDOUT (1 << 1)
#define CHILD_PIPE_STDERR (1 << 2)

#define READ_END 0
#define WRITE_END 1


struct child
child_spawn(const char * const argv[], const char * const env[], int flags)
{
  int in_pipe[2] = {-1, -1};
  int out_pipe[2] = {-1, -1};
  int err_pipe[2] = {-1, -1};

  if (flags & CHILD_PIPE_STDIN)
    if (pipe(in_pipe))
      error(EXIT_FAILURE, errno, "pipe(in_pipe) failed");

  if (flags & CHILD_PIPE_STDOUT)
    if (pipe(out_pipe))
      error(EXIT_FAILURE, errno, "pipe(out_pipe) failed");

  if (flags & CHILD_PIPE_STDERR)
    if (pipe(err_pipe))
      error(EXIT_FAILURE, errno, "pipe(err_pipe) failed");

  pid_t p = child_spawn_fd(argv, env,
               in_pipe[READ_END],
               out_pipe[WRITE_END],
               err_pipe[WRITE_END]);

  if (p == -1)
    error(EXIT_FAILURE, errno, "fork() failed");

  close_if_valid(in_pipe[READ_END]);
  close_if_valid(out_pipe[WRITE_END]);
  close_if_valid(err_pipe[WRITE_END]);

  struct child c =
    {
      .pid = p,
      .fd_in = in_pipe[WRITE_END],
      .fd_out = out_pipe[READ_END],
      .fd_err = err_pipe[READ_END],
    };

  return c;
}

/* 
   Safer implementation of `system()`. It does not invoke shell, and takes
   command as NULL terminated list of execuatable and parameters
*/
int
my_system(const char * const argv[])
{
  struct child c = child_spawn(argv, NULL, 0);

  int status = child_wait(&c);

  if (WIFEXITED(status))
    return WEXITSTATUS(status);
  else
    return -1;
}




int
main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  printf("Running 'ls -l' using my_system()\n"); 
  printf("---------------------------------\n");
  fflush(stdout);

  const char * ls_argv[] =
    {
      "/bin/ls",
      "-l",
      NULL
    };

  int e = my_system(ls_argv);
  printf("---------\n");
  printf("\exit code ---> %d\n", e); 



  printf("\nRunning 'ls -l' using child_spawn() and reading from stdout\n"); 
  printf("-----------------------------------------------------------\n");
  fflush(stdout);

  struct child c = child_spawn(ls_argv, NULL, CHILD_PIPE_STDOUT);

  /* 
     Read from the childs stdout and write to current stdout
  */
  size_t copied = 0;
  while (1)
    {
      char buff[4096];

      ssize_t rlen = read(c.fd_out, buff, 4096);
      if (rlen == -1)
    error(EXIT_FAILURE, errno, "read() failed");

      if (rlen == 0)
    break;

      size_t written = 0;
      while (written < rlen)
    {
      ssize_t wlen = write(1, buff + written, rlen - written);
      if (wlen == -1)
        error(EXIT_FAILURE, errno, "write() failed");

      written += wlen;
    }
      copied += written;
    }


  /* Wait for child to end */
  int status = child_wait(&c);

  printf("---------\n");

  if (WIFEXITED(status))
    {  
      printf("  ---> child exited normally with exit code %d and with %ld bytes copied\n",
         WEXITSTATUS(status),
         copied);
    }
  else
    printf("  ---> child exited by som other reason than _exit()");


  printf("\nWriting to Elmer Fudd filter\n"); 
  const char *quote = "Be very very quiet, I'm hunting rabbits!\n";

  printf("Original text: %s", quote);

  printf("-----------------------------------------------------------\n");
  fflush(stdout);

  const char *fudd_filter[] =
    {"/bin/sed", "-e" "s/r/w/g", NULL};  

  struct child c2 = child_spawn(fudd_filter, NULL, CHILD_PIPE_STDIN);
  size_t qlen = strlen(quote);
  const char *q = quote;

  while (qlen)
    {
      ssize_t wlen = write(c2.fd_in, q, qlen);
      if (wlen == -1)
    error(EXIT_FAILURE, errno, "write() failed");

      q += wlen;
      qlen -= wlen;
    }

  child_wait(&c2);
}
```